# List variable inside a query Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have created a variable that returns a list ids of menus from the database. I have then put the variable in another query that returns meals in a list.   My issue is that I keep on recieving the error Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<int?>` to `int?`

```
var getmenuids = (from r in db.Menus
                  where (r.Restaurantid == currentrestaurant)
                  select r.Id).ToList();

var meals = db.Meals.Where(r => r.MenuID = getmenuids).ToList();
```

Comment: db.Meals.Where(r => getmenuids.Contains(r.MenuID)).ToList();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're having an issue because you're using `==` (comparing a single element to a list) instead of `Contains()` (searching for the an element *in* the list).

```
var meals = db.Meals.Where(r => getmenuids.Contains(r.MenuID)).ToList();
```

You could combine these too.. something like this:

```
var meals = (from meal in db.Meals
             join menu in db.Menus on meal.MenuID equals menu.Id
             where menu.Restaurantid == currentrestaurant
             select meal).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that `getmenuids` is a collection of `int?` values but you compare it to `r.MenuID` which is typed to `int?`.  To fix this you need to search `getmenuids` for `r.MenuId`

```
db.Meals.Where(r => getmenuids.Contains(r.MenuID)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the list with MenuID. getmenuids is a list.

```
r.MenuID = getmenuids
```